# mix between pure and Impure pipes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pipes-filters

Is it possible to have pipe which behaves like impure pipes, but not to be executed on every fired event. For example i want to create translate pipe, which to be executed only on a language dropdown value change

Answer (score 2):

Use a cache. For each translation save original and translation.

For each call to the pipe, search in the cache, if it exists use it else make the translation and save in the cache.

Use a injectable service that store the cache.

When language dropdown change, clear the cache ;)

Answer (score 0):

This question is old. But since there is no accepted answer yet, let me add my thought too.

You can add [parameters](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#parameterizing-a-pipe) to the pipe. When the parameter changes, the pipe will call the `transform` function.

Just as @Javier said, you could use an injectable service to store the different translation cache. In the `transform` function, you will check the parameter and use it as a key to get the translation from the service.